Bathroom sink drain gurgling but not clogged - plumbing design issue?
My bathroom sink drains, but often times after draining, there will be a gurgling sound.  It is not clogged, I ran a lot of water down without issue.
I did some research which indicated the design of the plumbing could be an issue.  It appears to be an amateur job, so I have attached some pictures.
What is the proper way to connect the sink to the drain pipe that comes out of the wall?




Gurgling usually points to a vent issue, not getting enough air in.  Would check those two clamps are tight/give them an extra turn, but is just simple/probably not important.  The plumbing vent probably has a partial clog, bird/animal nests/bodies.
